# Tracking the location of files downloaded through internet on Windows Phone

Tags: apps

I have the following problem with my Nokia Lumia 520 windows phone:

I have downloaded a few apps & Videos through internet from my mobile and I am not able to find the specific folder or drive to where those files were downloaded?

Once the download gets finished, the download window gets expired and thats it ?!

Could you please help me out to locate them and bring back before i mess up with it?

Answer (score 3):

**Applications and Games**

[Application for Windows Phone are downloaded exclusively from the Marketplace. All downloaded and installed application are visible in the Applications list (from the Start screen, flick left).](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-CA/how-to/wp7/apps/find-and-buy-apps-in-marketplace)

**Pictures, video, audio and other media**

- Downloaded from the marketplace: all items downloaded in this way go in to the `Pictures` or `Music+Videos` hubs based on the type of media. Both the `Pictures` and `Music+Videos` hubs can also be seen on the Applications list(from the Start screen, flick left).
- Synced from your PC: as above, all items go into their respective hubs.
- From a web browser: you can stream and view videos and images in this way but cannot save them on to the phones file system directly through the phone. These will have to be synced through your PC.